# PHP jQuery get array and display correctly

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've got an AJAX request in my `index.php` to another file (`get_code.php`) that queries a DB and returns a `json_encode`d array to `index.php`, where it is converted to a string with `JSON_stringify`.

This works fine, but for the fact that it comes out on the page like so:

```
[{"code":"GG500","desc":"Desc 1","price1":"9.35","price2":"8.25","price3":"7.75","avg":"7.994198","lwcm":"7.9568","cost":"4.63"},
{"code":"GGC4","desc":"Desc 2","price1":"","price2":"","price3":"","avg":"504.666666","lwcm":"387.5","cost":"260.61"}]
```

## Question:

How can I get this string and convert it into a normal array or whatever that I can display in an HTML table in `index.php`?

***Current code:***

**index.php** jQuery

```
if (!data.result) {
   $('#modal2').modal('show');
   $('.msgs').text(data.error);
   $('#cdnf').text(data.code);
   $('#tarray').text(JSON.stringify(data.tarray));
}
```

**index.php** HTML

```
<p id="tarray"></p><!-- needs to be a table -->
```

**get_code.php** PHP

```
$taq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM variants")or die(mysql_error());
if($taq){
    $tarray = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($taq)){
            $tarray[] = array(
     'code' => $row['va_code'],
     'desc' => $row['va_description'],
     'price1' => $row['price_1'],
     'price2' => $row['price_2'],
     'price3' => $row['price_3'],
     'avg' => $row['average_price'],
     'lwcm' => $row['lwcm'],            
     'cost' => $row['cost']  
);
    }
};
die(json_encode(['tarray' => $tarray]));
```

Comment: you need to iterate the json object. Read the object and then print the values

Comment: JSON.parse is for decoding json into an array, JSON.stringify is for encoding array into json

Comment: OK thanks @Tushar - how do I go about this in the jQuery?

Comment: @hassan JSON.parse returns an error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` ?

Comment: depends on how you want to show the data. ;) you can create a table and populate each row or you can directly dump the data. It all depends on the requirement

Comment: @Tushar the idea was to create the table and populate each row

Comment: Your output `json` is not proper, there is no way (obvious/easy way) to distinguish between objects.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` instead of  `JSON.parse(data.tarray)` , you may need to show more of your index.php code

Comment: @ErrHunter OK Thanks. Only reason I used `JSON` was because it just returns `[object Object]` if you don't

Comment: give us your proper JSON and I will show you how to display it in a table

Comment: @hassan question edited - don't know if what you're suggesting is possible?

Comment: @joel2703 You need to find a way to generate proper `json` from `php`. Once that is done, generating table is easy.

Comment: @Tushar what else do you need? All of the string it returns? I will edit the question if that's what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('#tarray').text(JSON.stringify(data.tarray));
```

loop over the data and create a table:

```
$('#tarray').html('').append(
    $('<table>').append(
        $('<tr>').append(
            $.map(data.tarray[0] || [], function (_, key) {
                return $('<th>').text(key);
            })
        ),
        data.tarray.map(function (row) {
            return $('<tr>').append(
                $.map(row, function (cell) {
                    return $('<td>').text(cell);
                })
            );
        })
    )
);
```

```js
// Sample data
var data = {
    tarray: [{"code":"GG500","desc":"Desc 1","price1":"9.35","price2":"8.25","price3":"7.75","avg":"7.994198","lwcm":"7.9568","cost":"4.63"},
{"code":"GGC4","desc":"Desc 2","price1":"","price2":"","price3":"","avg":"504.666666","lwcm":"387.5","cost":"260.61"}]
};

$('#tarray').html('').append(
    $('<table>').append(
        $('<tr>').append(
            $.map(data.tarray[0] || [], function (_, key) {
                return $('<th>').text(key);
            })
        ),
        data.tarray.map(function (row) {
            return $('<tr>').append(
                $.map(row, function (cell) {
                    return $('<td>').text(cell);
                })
            );
        })
    )
);
```

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tarray"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: how would I set it to nothing, so that if it's queried again the table's empty?

Comment: Add `.html('')` before the first `.append`. I updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is as per OP's need. I am just showing here an example of your correct JSON and how to iterate to get that in form of a table

Correct JSON object would look like below :

```
[{"code":"ABC123","desc":"Example description","price1":"3.00"},
  {"code":"BDC234","desc":"Example description2","price1":"3.50"}]
```

---

JSON into a table:

```js
var obj=[{"code":"ABC123","desc":"Example description","price1":"3.00"},{
  "code":"BDC234","desc":"Example description2","price1":"3.50"}]
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["code"]+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["desc"]+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["price1"]+"</td></tr>";

       $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 

    }
```

```css
#mytable{
 padding:0px;
}
tr,td{
border: 1px solid black;
padding:5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'></div>
```

Comment: awesome, so do i set `var obj=JSON.stringify(data.tarray);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tushar